# Animated show with transforming or talking cars fighting like gladiators

Tags: story-identification, tv, robots, animation

I remember this show from my childhood, probably between 1990 and 2000. I remember it was 3D animated. There were transforming cars (it was not *Transformers*) or they were talking cars.

I was watching it from a CD, I think it was the second part of the show. The robots were closed behind bars, and were fighting like gladiators. I think that there was some love story with one of the main characters too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When you say this isn't _Transformers_ though, do you just mean that it isn't the original series from the 1980s? Or are you confident that this isn't _any_ version of _Transformers_ at all? There've been quite a few different _Transformers_ series' over the last 35 years, some of them 3D-animated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly [*Gladiformers*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/Gladiformers)?

> *Gladiformers* is a 2007 film by Vídeo Brinquedo. The plot revolves around a Prince named Julius Drive who was sold into slavery (somehow) and forced to fight to the death in the mechanical slaughterhouse known as The Centaris Gladitorial Arena's. The movie has loads of Angra songs thrown in and it did well enough in its home country to have a sequel but it sadly has never been dubbed in English.

### Trailer

Comment: it's exactly this!!! thank you very much about it!